# How can I export to Drive an ee.List in GEE?

Tags: google-earth-engine

Following GEE code was used for producing an **ee.List** of [year, month, day, daily precipitation] for CHIRPS/DAILY images filtered by date ('2015-01-01', '2016-01-01') and by using a point **ee.Reducer** (location of my weather station).

```
//Selecting Image Collection of dayly precipitation
var chirps = ee.ImageCollection("UCSB-CHG/CHIRPS/DAILY");

var precip = chirps
  .filterDate('2015-01-01', '2016-01-01'); //366 days (leap year)

var count = precip.size();

// Print the filtered precipitation ImageCollection. 
print('precipitation series:', precip);

var getDatePrecip = function(image) {
  // weather station place: Valle de la Pascua 
  var p = ee.Geometry.Point(-66.00, 9.22);

  // Reducing region and getting value
  var value = ee.Image(image)
    .reduceRegion(ee.Reducer.first(), p).get('precipitation');

  var time = ee.Image(image).get('system:time_start');

  // Return the time (in milliseconds since Jan 1, 1970) as a Date
  var precipit_list = ee.Date(time)
    .format()
    .slice(0,10)
    .split('-')
    .add(value);

  return precipit_list;
};

var precipit_list = precip.toList(count).map(getDatePrecip);

print(precipit_list);
```

Result, as expected, it is an **ee.List** with following structure:

```
.
.
.
132:
["2015","05","13",1.8483211994171143]
133: 
["2015","05","14",0]
134: 
["2015","05","15",0]
135: 
["2015","05","16",0]
136: 
["2015","05","17",0]
137: 
["2015","05","18",5.3127264976501465]
138: 
["2015","05","19",10.625452995300293]
139: 
["2015","05","20",5.3127264976501465]
140: 
["2015","05","21",5.391742706298828]
141: 
["2015","05","22",0]
142: 
["2015","05","23",0]
143: 
["2015","05","24",0]
144:
.
.
.
```

and it can be also flattened to following structure by using flatten **ee.List** method:

```
.
.
.
551: 
5.3127264976501465
552: 
2015
553: 
05
554: 
19
555: 
10.625452995300293
556: 
2015
557: 
05
558: 
20
559: 
5.3127264976501465
560: 
2015
561: 
05
562: 
21
563: 
5.391742706298828

.
.
.
```

My question is how can I export to Drive whatever of these **ee.List**s in GEE? I tried out several approach (by using Export.table.toDrive) without any succeed. I could not find out any method to convert an **ee.List** in a FeatureCollection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add these lines below your code, run it and start the task on the "Tasks" tab.

```
// weather station place: Valle de la Pascua 
var p = ee.Geometry.Point(-66.00, 9.22);

var myFeatures = ee.FeatureCollection(precipit_list.map(function(el){
  el = ee.List(el); // cast every element of the list
  var geom = p;
  return ee.Feature(geom, {
    'year':ee.Number(el.get(0)), 
    'month':ee.Number(el.get(1)),
    'day':ee.Number(el.get(2)),
    'value':ee.Number(el.get(3))
  });
}));

Map.addLayer(myFeatures); // see the result
Map.centerObject(myFeatures);

// Export features, specifying corresponding names.
Export.table.toDrive(myFeatures,
"myTask",
"myExportFolder",
"myList", 
"CSV");
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It produces same result with normal or flattened list. With 'SHP' extension produces a point shapefile with 365 records or features. It was only a test because this makes no sense.